# Does asciidoctor have a setting to remove the <paragraph> and <p> tags from the source it outputs?

Tags: html, asciidoctor

I am developing a custom filter in Drupal using asciidoctor and realize that asciidoctor places the output in `<div class="paragraph"><p>` tags.

Does it have a setting to remove those tags from the output and return just the inner HTML?

Answer (score 1):

There is a different output plugin [HTML5s](https://github.com/jirutka/asciidoctor-html5s) that creates semantic HTML with fewer extra tags. It works both in Ruby and JavaScript environments.