# How can I remove the enclosing tags around a piece of HTML?

Tags: php, regex, html-content-extraction

I am creating a custom filter for text using the asciidoc syntax for Drupal using the [customfilter](https://drupal.org/project/customfilter) module. I enclose it in [asciidoc][/asciidoc] tags and when I run it through the `asciidoctor` command the output is enclosed in `<div class="paragraph"><p>` tags.

Output like this in which I am using the [asciidoc] tag to format html links comes out like this.

```
On the markup side Drupal's contrib `markdown` filter has been somewhat iffy,
and so has the `bbcode` filter. Looking around for other more compact documenting
systems led me to the https://asciidoc.org[Asciidoc] utility and its more
advanced brother https://asciidoctor.org[Asciidoctor]. In combination with another
 Drupal module called https://drupal.org/project/customfilter[customfilter] which
makes it easy to create your own filters, I think I have hit on a combination
of modules which allow me as much freedom and fine control on my pages as I want.
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
<p>On the markup side Drupal&#8217;s contrib <code>markdown</code> filter has been somewhat iffy,
and so has the <code>bbcode</code> filter. Looking around for other more compact documenting
systems led me to the <a href="https://asciidoc.org">Asciidoc</a> utility and its more
advanced brother <a href="https://asciidoctor.org">Asciidoctor</a>. In combination with another
 Drupal module called <a href="https://drupal.org/project/customfilter">customfilter</a> which
makes it easy to create your own filters, I think I have hit on a combination
of modules which allow me as much freedom and fine control on my pages as I want.</p>
</div>
```

Is there some PHP function that can take a string HTML and the set of enclosing tags to string, and return the inner HTML they enclose? Or perhaps some regex expression which can match the portion between the tags?

This is the desired output

```html
On the markup side Drupal&#8217;s contrib <code>markdown</code> filter has been somewhat iffy,
and so has the <code>bbcode</code> filter. Looking around for other more compact documenting
systems led me to the <a href="https://asciidoc.org">Asciidoc</a> utility and its more
advanced brother <a href="https://asciidoctor.org">Asciidoctor</a>. In combination with another
 Drupal module called <a href="https://drupal.org/project/customfilter">customfilter</a> which
makes it easy to create your own filters, I think I have hit on a combination
of modules which allow me as much freedom and fine control on my pages as I want.
```

I asked a related question if asciidoc could be configured to avoid enclosing the output in `<div class="paragraph"><p>...</p></div>`  - [Does asciidoctor have a setting to remove the <paragraph> and <p> tags from the source it outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859883/does-asciidoctor-have-a-setting-to-remove-the-paragraph-and-p-tags-from-the)

Comment: `strip-tags` is wrong for this purpose. The purpose is to strip only outer tags because they create additional paragraphs. eg if I prefer to use asciidoc URLs and use `[asciidoc]https://asciidoctor.org[Asciidoctor][/asciidoc]` around the URLs the filter will create paragraphs around the URLs which will break the flow of the text. `strip-enclosing-tags` would be more like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through pure PHP you may use `DOMDocument` which i don't recommend using cause it is slow and you will get in trouble tracing its errors and so. For the same reason I am not gonna explain more about that object. Just a link from the official website:

[PHP DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Note: I personally prefer using `DomDocument` when you work with large texts for example i used to read the whole page and get all the elements one by one which was nearly impossible with regex. In that case i used `DomDocument`.

Lets get back to your topic. Your example shows that you are not parsing large chunks so i recommend using `Regex`.

```
preg_match_all( '/<p>(?P<content>.*?)<\/p>/s' ,$text, $ref );
var_dump($ref['content']);
```

The above regex gives you all the elements beetwen `p` tag.

You may play with it and make a new one like this:

```
preg_match_all( '/<div class="paragraph">\s<p>(?P<content>.*?)<\/*p>\s<\/*div>/' ,$text, $ref );
```

which gives you everything between div tags( the tags may have any attribute ).

Also see the link below on regex

[Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed the second regex does not remove the first `<p>` in the output. How can it be fixed?

Comment: When I insert a `<p>xxxx</p>` in the text, the match ends on the newly introduced `</p>` when it should match the `</p>` before the div tag which matches the opening `<div class="paragraph">`. How can that also fixed?

Comment: You're welcome. About your first comment, Yes the second regex also returns `p` elems but the first one is what you want. it gives you all the things between `p` tags. Also see my new edit.
About the second comment i don't really get what you mean i hope my new edit helps.

Comment: I have adjusted the new regex to this `'/<div class="paragraph">\s<p>(?P<content>.*?)<\/*div>/s' and the result is displayed at https://regex101.com/r/lkKuKt/2. What I need is for the content match to exclude the closing `</p>` tag.

Comment: @vfclists try this one. `<div class="paragraph">\s<p>(?P<content>.*?)<\/*p>\s<\/*div>`

Comment: Thanks. This one **Hits The Spot!!**. Even with additional <p> and </div> tags inserted it still works.